# $.ajax will not work within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having trouble with this function using jquery's ajax. Essentially this function checks an api to see if a variable called "success" is true. If it is, I want this function to return true. If success is false, I want it to return false.

Here is my code:

```
function loggedIn() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/auth",
        success: function (a) {
            if (a.success == "true") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code is actually in a document (myjs.js, etc), and is called into the html file AFTER jquery and BEFORE the function is actually called. I have a script tag in the HTML where this function is called. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        if (loggedIn() == true) {
            $('#send-to-user-btn').css('display', 'block');
            $('#sign-in-button-btn').css('display', 'none');
            $('#login-bar-my').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I put a `console.log(loggedIn());` in the script tags, but it comes back undefined.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any parameter to access api, then add it. Also display webpage screen shot with console.log  to understand more. Give alert option in different stages to understand where is call and where is not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using all of the answers, I was able to merge (mostly Terry's answer) them to come up with a solution that works. (Thanks for all the answers btw!). This is the myjs.js file:

```
function loggedIn() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/auth",
    });
}
```

This is the script page, I added () after loggedIn and everything seems to work perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loggedIn().done(function(response) {
        if (response.success == 'true') {
             // If loggedIn returns success
            $('#send-to-user-btn').css('display', 'block');
            $('#sign-in-button-btn').css('display', 'none');
            $('#login-bar-my').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            // Otherwise...
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since AJAX is asynchronous in nature, you cannot simply check the value returned from the function. You are not guaranteed to receive a response from the API endpoint when you call the AJAX function at runtime.

Instead, what you want is to check the value when the promise, returned from the asynchronous request, has been resolved. Here is what you can do:

1. In the `loggedIn()` function, return the `$.ajax()` object instead. It is a jqXHR object which you can add methods like `.done()` (fired when successful), `.fail()` (fired when an error has been encountered)`, or`.always()` (which is always run upon completion).
2. Since you want to listen to success, simply do `loggedIn.done()`. The callback in within is where you can implement additional logic to check if your logged in attempt was successful (i.e. by checking of the `success` key is true).

Using the `jqXHR.success` callback in `$.ajax` is strongly discouraged now: it is officially deprecated in 1.8 and **removed in 3.0** (and that is one of the reasons why so many plugins/sites break when they upgrade to jQuery 3).

Here is an example:

```
$(function() {
    // Return promise
    var loggedIn = function () {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/auth"
        });
    };

    loggedIn().done(function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
             // If loggedIn returns success
            $('#send-to-user-btn').css('display', 'block');
            $('#sign-in-button-btn').css('display', 'none');
            $('#login-bar-my').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            // Otherwise...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: much better answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a result from the `ajax` call. You need to put your logic inside the `success` function callback. Also you can use `Promise based` approach

```
function loggedIn() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/auth",
        success: function (a) {
            if (a.success == "true") {
                   return Promise.resolve("true");
            } else {
                   return Promise.reject("someValue");
            }
        }
    });
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        loggedIn().then(res => {
            $('#send-to-user-btn').css('display', 'block');
            $('#sign-in-button-btn').css('display', 'none');
            $('#login-bar-my').css('display', 'none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is still incorrect: the AJAX function will not return any results rightaway (i.e. at runtime) because it is asynchronous in nature.

Comment: Did you even test the code out yourself? AJAX is asynchronous: when you run `loggedIn()` it is not guaranteed to return anything (and most likely will not)

Comment: Based on OP's code, he will try to use `console.log(loggedIn())`, or pass it to some variable, e.g. `var data = loggedIn()`. In this case it will always return undefined.

Comment: Instead of mixing things together like that I would suggest to use the Promise-like behaviour of .ajax and keep true/false return in the loggedIn fn and do `loggedIn().then((result) => your logic...)`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax, internally invokes xhr object of the browser, which is processed asynchronously by the browser, hence, the control that you invoke by calling `loggedIn` function gets over, all it does is to register an ajax request, which browser makes separately to the server.

change your function to accept a callback like below:

```
function loggedIn(successCallBack) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/auth",
        success: function (a) {
             if(typeof successCallBack == 'function'){
                 successCallBack(a.success);
             }
        }
    });
}
```

and call it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        loggedIn(function(result){
               if (result) {
                   $('#send-to-user-btn').css('display', 'block');
                   $('#sign-in-button-btn').css('display', 'none');
                   $('#login-bar-my').css('display', 'none');
            } else {
                // Your logic here
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your */api/auth* controller returns JSON object with `success` property of data field, then you could use external variable. Set `async` option to `false` to prevent asynchronous execution.

```
function loggedIn() { 
  let isAuthorized = false;
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/api/auth", 
    async: false,
    success: function (a) { 
      isAutorized = (a.success == "true");
    }
  });
  return isAuthorized;
}
```

But synchronous AJAX is strongly discouraged (see details in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). 
Instead, you could send any function to `loggedIn` as parameter to execute one if authorization request is succeeds. For example:

```
function loggedIn(delegate) { 
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "/api/auth", 
    success: function (a) { 
      if (a.success == "true") delegate();
    }
  });
}

// Call LoggedIn with delegate:
loggedIn(function() {
  $('#send-to-user-btn').css('display', 'block'); 
  $('#sign-in-button-btn').css('display', 'none'); 
  $('#login-bar-my').css('display', 'none');
});

//or
var setStyle = function() {
  $('#send-to-user-btn').css('display', 'block'); 
  $('#sign-in-button-btn').css('display', 'none'); 
  $('#login-bar-my').css('display', 'none');
};
loggedIn(setStyle);
```

Comment: This won't work. The Ajax fn is asynchronous and therefore your method will always return `false`

Comment: @PeterPajchl , `a` is not a function, `a` is a `data` argument of success function that will returned from */api/auth* controller. See definition of `success` property of [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.

Comment: I am not referring to the callback in my statement but in the end it is exactly this success callback (when successful) that will be executed at the "next tick" at best. In other words the return statement of the loggedIn fn will be executed before any callback method of the Ajax call.

Comment: @PeterPajchl , what do you think now?

Comment: this will work and callbacks is one way of solving the asynchronous behaviour but I would advise to rather use Promises or based on your env. even simplify with async/await. Callbacks have to nest pointing to infamous callback hell.